# Sybase add current user id on insert and update to the table

Tags: database, sybase

I need to track user making inserts and updates on Sybase table.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: sybase is company not a product!!

Comment: This is true, but unhelpful.  The OP probably means Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Please use trigger to track all the inserts and updates. For every action store/update USER name in a particular column say, modifier.

Comment: How can I in support insert trigger update column that has not been inserted yet?

Comment: This is smth I've been thinking about however I am not able to do it in Sybase. Can you please provide working code for this problem?